# How do I pass a value to re-matches as a regular expression instead of a string constant

Tags: regex, clojure

I am trying to pass a value into clojure's re-matches function for a regular expression like so

```
(defn extract-val
[k data]
  (let [r (format ".*\"%s\":\"(.*?)\".*" k)
        v ((last (re-matches #(str r) data)))]
 v))
```

Calling this function as
    (extract-val "event" "{\"event\":\"data\"}")

throws a class cast exception with a message that says cannot be cast to java.util.regex.Pattern clojure.core/re-matcher

Is there any way to do this or do i have to use the regex.Pattern directly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#(str r)` creates an anonymous function of 0 arguments which evaluates `str r` when called. You can create a pattern with `re-pattern`:

```
(last (re-matches (re-pattern r) data)
```

You should use a parser rather than regex if you're processing JSON however.